# HTACCESS Clean URL without breaking the Query String

Tags: php, .htaccess

This code below does exactly what I wanted to do, but the problem is that it breaks the query string. Whatever am passing into the URL is not being recognized by PHP $_GET. Is there a way I can use this code and also not break and query string am using on URL.

I' am just a beginner with HTACCESS, I do not have much knowledge about this.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?([-\w]+)?/?$ index.php?slug1=$1&slug2=$2&slug3=$3&slug4=$4&slug5=$5
```

Comment: Use the flag `[QSA]`. But you haven't 5 capturing groups in your regex. I only see 3 of them. But in your redirect you're referencing to 5.

Comment: Thanks TiMESPLiNTER for your help....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original query string is automatically added to the substitution URL *unless* you specify a query string in the substitution URL explicitly. In that case, you have to use the `[QSA]` flag in the rewrite rule to merge the original query string into the substitution query string.

For details, see what the documentation of [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) says about "Modifying the Query String".

Comment: Exactly. [QSA] - Query String Append.
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa